# Proof that independent weak classifier voting works

Tags: machine-learning, binomial-distribution

Assume $m$ independent binary classifiers with probability $p$ to be correct $p>0.5$. Show that the probability of a voting, e.g. decision is made by the majority of classifiers is correct with probability $q>p$.

I think this problem as equivalent to showing that the Binomial cumulative distribution $\text{CDF}(k,n,p)$ follows $\text{CDF}(k=m/2, m, p) < 1-p$

Answer (score 0):

$z=\sum_i{x_i}\text{   ; } \Pr(C)=\Pr(z>m/2)\\
\text{Markov's Inequality: } 
\Pr(X\geq a)\leq {\frac {\mathbb {E} (X)}{a}}.\\
\text{define } y=m-z \text{ then } Pr(\epsilon)=\Pr(y\ge m/2)\le \frac{m(1-p)}{m/2}=1/2(1-p)\\
\Pr(C)=1-\Pr(\epsilon)>(p+1)/2>p$

Comment: my answer is wrong. I mistakenly divided by 2 instead of multiplying by 2. What's the correct solution?